# css blueprint, create a div floating next to container div ? image attached

Tags: css, html, compass-sass, mockups, blueprint

Im trying to have a blueprint layout wich is 950px so I do something like the image below:

[image]

Like regular the 950px container ( right box ) is floating center page 
Now I'm in the need of having a #menu div floating left towards this 950px box, it should be positioned left to this #container 950px div and have a fixed width.

How can such a thing be accomplished? I tried already several css tricks to no avail, i know there is liquid layout but then the space between #menu and #container will become to big I want that space to be fixed like in below example say 20px the blueprint default.

**anyone knows how to make this happen and have the divs stay on page even when screen resizes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understood your question this will do what you want:

```
 body, html 
 {
    width: 100%;
 }

 <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 1100px">
    <div style="width: 150px; float:left;">
       menu
    </div>
    <div style="width: 950px; float:left;">
       right part
    </div>
 </div>
```